# Optical interferometer using software

Tags: telescopes, interferometry

I understand that optical interferometer is a technique by which we can combine light from multiple telescopes and combine them in optical interferometer to simulate effect of larger telescope with mirror diameter of largest distance between any two telescopes.

Currently telescopes use complex process of combining light obtained from different telescopes using beam combiner, this has limitation of telescopes to be colocated at the same place with interferometer arrangement in place. 
Is it possible to combine the light collected from two telescopes via software to produce same effect as optical interferometer which can allow us to treat telescopes located at large distances as a single telescope? Is there any software solution already available for that?

Answer (score 1):

It works fine with radio telescopes. The oscillating electric fields in the radio range can be measured as a function of time, displayed on oscilloscopes, waveforms can be digitized. After that one can do amazing things in software: http://www.lofar.org/

At the frequencies of visible light we cannot do that (yet). So interference has to be done in hardware.

Comment: What would it require?  Extremely accurate timing, perhaps?